# Debug & run result differ in simple c app that redirects stdout using freopen

Tags: c, system, stdout, freopen

I'm using linux manjaro. I have the following code (cons.c)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    FILE *f=freopen("/dev/null", "a", stdout); //redirect stdout to /dev/null
    FILE *g=freopen ("/dev/tty", "a", stdout); // redirect stdout back to console
    printf("%p %p\n",f,g);
    return 1;
}
```

I executed the following and got the expected result

```
[tom@sp4 src]$ gcc -g cons.c -o cons
[tom@sp4 src]$ ./cons
0x7f19897b7520 0x7f19897b7520
```

When I set a breakpoint on the bottom line and debug with the VS Code interactive debuggers however g returns null and the printf does nothing.

Comment: `void main()` is not a conforming signature for a C `main()` function on a hosted implementation.  `main()` should return `int`.  However, this is unlikely to be the source of your problem.

Comment: I can't reproduce the behavior you describe.  For me, your program always prints "0 256 0", whether it is run directly or from gdb, whether with or without a breakpoint set.  This is what I would expect.

Comment: @John Bollinger Thanks. int main() didn't make a difference. I'm running it in a vs code terminal. Doubt that would make a difference either.

Comment: Actually, running it in a VS Code command window is *exactly* the kind of thing that could cause such a problem.  Try opening a genuine terminal window, separate from VS Code, and running your executable there.

Comment: You do not test the return values of your `freopen()` calls, so you do not know whether they succeed.  Failing to check the return values of your function calls is usually a mistake, and I suspect that it has bitten you here.  The behavior you describe is consistent with the second `freopen()` call failing, and the fact that you are running the program inside VS Code is a plausible explanation for that.

Comment: @John Bollinger You're right John. The second freopen returns null when debugging in vs code terminal but not when debugging in windows terminal. Many thanks for your help.

Comment: Please make this an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies with the interactive debuggers in VS Code. It works fine when debugging using gdb in a VS Code terminal. When using the interactive debuggers in VS code the second reopen returns null. Thanks to John Bollinger.